# PHP: Time Stamp

Tags: php

I want to use current timestamp and assign next minute to database for some cron function. That is, if it is 7 hr 30 min 20 sec, then I want to start from 7 hr 31 min 0 sec. I am facing some strange issue.

If I do-

```
$current_time_stamp = time() + 1*60;
```

it does not start exactly from next minute. But if I do-

```
$current_time_stamp = number_format(time()/60);
$current_time_stamp = $current_time_stamp*60 + 1*60;
```

it gives some weird time in year 1970. Please point out the error.

Comment: $ts = strtotime('+1 minute')

Comment: I added an explanation for number_format() in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time() function for this, no need for `mktime` or `strtotime`

```
$nextmin = ceil(time()/60)*60;
```

However, `strtotime` can be used like this

```
$nextmin=floor(strtotime("+1 minute"));
```

the function `number_format()` expects at least two parameters, the number to format, and the number of decimal places. You have to put the number of decimals in it.

Comment: thanks a lot ... please tell why number_format() does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_time_stamp = time() + 1*60;
```

This will work. Of course set the NEW time, when STARTING the cronjob - not at the end, as then you would need to substract the duration of the cron to get exactly one minute.

It would be even better not to use `time()`, but the old timestamp you had in the database.

Comment: he also needs to round the seconds: 1m20s -> 2m00s for example

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = time();
$time = strtotime(date(sprintf('Y-m-d H:%02d:00', floor(date('i', $time) / 5) * 5), $time)); // round up to 5 minutes
```

example for rounding to 5 minutes. For the one minute it will be easier

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:00', time()));
// you will get floor time.
$time = strtotime('+1 minute', $time); // increase time for 1 minute
```

You cant work with timestamp like that. Because timestamp has leap years and changes for timezones. simple mathematic functions dont consider this.

Comment: but sir it provides a numeric value. normal mathematical functions should work after i get the numeric value. ceil() is working fine, as suggested by others. my new question is why number_format() didnt work

Comment: Check return value for number_format. You will see value like this: 23,065,363 - it is not a valid number. Do you need further explantation ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> $next_minute = mktime( date( 'H' ), date( 'i' ) + 1, 0 );

Which is actually a shortcut of this:

> $next_minute = mktime( date( 'H' ), date( 'i' ) + 1, 0, date( 'd' ), date( 'm' ), date( 'Y' ) );

What it does is contruct a new timestamp from the arguments provided.

It's as simple as providing the following arguments:

1. current hour
2. current minute plus one
3. zero seconds
4. current date
5. current month
6. current year

Refer to [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

FYI, [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) will not work because it converts the timestamp into a string ( human readable format ) which PHP cannot use for calculations.

Comment: thanks. but php is able to use number_format() for calculations, if we specify number of decimals. i followed comment of helloworld and it worked well.